# BibTex suddenly unable to find bibliography files

Tags: bibtex

On one of my machines, Bibtex is now unable to find any .bib bibliography files, whether the .bib file is in ~/texmf/bibtex/bib/ and or even if I copy it into the local directory. This is a sudden issue, as Bibtex has worked fine on this machine for years; and I have similar setups on other machines and they remain working as usual.

I checked kpsewhich's report for texmf.cnf:

```
$ kpsewhich texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

This contains (as well as other settings), the following lines:

```
% pBibTeX bibliographies and style files.
BIBINPUTS.pbibtex       = .;$TEXMF/{pbibtex,bibtex}/bib//
BSTINPUTS.pbibtex       = .;$TEXMF/{pbibtex,bibtex}/bst//
```

Which I believe are the relevant settings for bibtex to look for .bib files in ~/texmf/bibtex/bib/ and the local directory.

So I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: What is the exact error message BibTeX is giving you?

Comment: @Johannes_B xelatex reports `Latexmk: Failed to find one or more bibliography files:  'bibliography_main.bib'`. bibtex reports `I couldn't open database file bibliography_main.bib`.

Comment: My guess is the underscore in the filename might be creating havoc.  Possibly enclose filename in double quotes `"..."`

Comment: ...though I would add that, with my TeX distribution, I have no problem creating a bibliography using BibTeX when the `.bib` filename contains underscores.

Comment: `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMF` etc. will show the value of the variables being used.  Also there is a `-debug` flat you can try to get information about the concrete lookup process.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've had the underscore for years and it's worked fine, and it works on all of my three other machines.

Answer (score 2):

Some boring thoughts:

1. Perhaps your BIB file is read-protected? This was a problem for me some time ago.
2. Did you change something since the last time when BibTeX worked?
3. Do you use a fully updated TeX distribution?
4. Do you work with different drives? (O. k, since .bib files are not working even in local directory this question is a bit useless, but nonetheless a possible error source)
5. Do you manipulate the BIBINPUTS variable somewhere?
6. What is the value of $TEXMF?

But I, personally, would bet that @Steven B. Segletes had the right idea and the honour is his.

Comment: It's odd, because it's essentially identical to the (working) setup on my other machines. BIB file is not read-protected, it's a fully up-to-date Texlive installation via Arch. I've sort of 'fixed' it, by uninstalling Arch's Texlive and installing Texlive via [Guix](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/download/) and this works, but it's not entirely satisfying not to understand why the working-for-years Arch packaged Texlive suddenly had this issue.